# How do rasterizers do so many computations per second, but shaders can't even come close?

Tags: gpu, shader

I am playing around on Shadertoy and I kept running into a hard loop count of about 12000 iterations, so I decided to check just how many calculations per frame it could do without dropping frames. Sure enough, the shaders don't seem to be able to anything more than 12000 calculations per frame without the frame rate dropping. This seems odd because I had thought that shaders run directly on the GPU, which regularly does way more calculations per polygon (like 100 calculations per 150K polygons!) with rasterizer software like OpenGL and Vulkan. So essentially my question is, how can I directly send calculations through the GPU like a rasterizer does to get the speedy data crunching that rasterizers do?

Comment: What is the content of each iterations? Is it 12000 iteration for the whole frame or per fragment? Can you give an example of code used to make the benchmark?

Comment: Yes sorry for the late reply, here is a link to a shadertoy I made to showcase the issue: https://www.shadertoy.com/view/7dXSRs

Comment: On this website, I can reach 1,500,000 without any big performance drop (which is suspicious because my GPU should not be able to do that so I think the code is well optimized by my graphic stack, possibly partially unrolled). Note that this is a pixel shader. So it applied for *each* pixel and *each* frame. Moreover, note that using loops in shader generally result in poor performance (especially when the result diverge between fragments). Thus, on a 800x600 screen at 60 FPS, the `mainImage` function is called 28,800,000 times per second.

Comment: Yes, your compiler probably optimized the loop out due to the constants, but for some reason mine doesn't so it shows me the cap of 15000. Also, don't rasterizers run for every pixel also? So it doesn't matter that it runs for every pixel because that cancels out when comparing to a rasterizer.

Comment: The optimizations are partially performed by the system and partially applied by the vendor. Optimizations are not mandatory and shared should be optimized to avoid such pattern. What GPU & OS do you have? Rasterizers are implemented in hardware directly, so they are much than using shader (programmable) for the same task. Moreover, rasterizers will actually likely never have to execute a loop of 15000 iteration per fragment as most scene does not have a lot of overlapping fragments (and 3D developers usually try to reduce the impact using several methods).

Comment: I'm on an RTX 2060 super on windows/chrome. "Moreover, rasterizers will actually likely never have to execute a loop of 15000 iteration per fragment as most scene does not have a lot of overlapping fragments" I thought that rasterizers have to check every triangle on screen to see if the pixel is in the triangle. This can easily exceed 15000 triangles on screen at a time. Also yes from what I have gathered so far, I have to make my own hardware for what I want to do. :(

Comment: I have a Nvidia card too on Windows so this is strange (GTX-1660S). "rasterizers have to check every triangle on screen to see if the pixel is in the triangle" no they don't. I think you confused ray-tracing with rasterization. Rasterization works by iterating first over triangles and not pixels: for each triangle, the rasterizer generates fragments that will be translated later to pixels in the graphic pipeline. It is far less costly iterating over each triangle than pixels because triangles are generally pretty small on the screen and not always visible.